# Is there a way to apply Break to this For loop?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to solve this code. The purpose of this code is to add to the array `Memo` the first empty spaces (Id as 0) found in the array.

But, somehow, the `break` isn't terminating the `for` loop (which leads to keep adding values...).

The expected result has to be 555550000000000,

But it's returning 000005555555555 instead.

Am I ignoring something? or maybe I have to use other type of cycle?

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int [] Memo = new int[15];
        foreach(int i in Memo)
        {
            Memo[i] = 0;
        }

        int Empty = 0;
        int size = 5;
        int Value = 5;
        int CheckPos;

        for(int x = 0; x < Memo.Length; x++)
        {
            if (Memo[x] == 0)
            {
                Empty++;
            }
            else
            {
                Empty = 0;
            }

            if (Empty == size)
            {
                CheckPos = x - size + 1;
                for (int j = CheckPos; j < size; j++)
                {
                    Memo[j] = Value;
                }
                break;
             }
        }

        foreach(int i in Memo)
        {
            Console.Write(Memo[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Watch carefully at the last loop. Ask yourself, What are you writing there?

Answer (score 1):

The content of the `Memo` is all right. The problem is how you print it in your `foreach` loop. The following structure will be more correct:

```
foreach (int i in Memo)
{
    Console.Write(i);
}
```

When you use `Console.Write(Memo[i]);` you're passing value of the element to be used as an index. Basically first 5 times you print element with index 5 and remaining times you print element with index 0.

Comment: As expected. Correct, but, in my opinion, you are not helping the OP giving them the fish.

Comment: I feel so terrible now... Thank you so much for the lesson and answer. I'll apply that in future.

Comment: or maybe... stay with fors... forever.

Comment: @scor4er yeah, I rarely use them, I heard and learned it was like a quick way to do a for... now I see it doesn't totally work and manipulates like one. Thank you for not being so rough with me.